# Dataset is NULL after clicking form button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataset

Dataset is NULL after clicking form button.

I want to learn and understand Visual Basic 2017.
On a test webform some textboxes are filled with dataset (DS) items (during pageload).
This works well without problems .

There is also a SAVE button on the form that must fill a textbox with a dataset item after clicking.
But then the dataaet appears to be to be NULL.
How is that possible?
I hope someone can tell me what is wrong, I understood thata dataset stays dukkws while running.

Aftr clicking the SAVEbutton this error appears: ==========================================
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
  at NW_DB_update_test.NWtest.testDS() in S:\P2 S VS tests\NW DB

## update test\NW DB update test\NWtest.aspx.vb:line 46

Thw VB soutce is ==================================

Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class NWtest
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Public DA As SqlDataAdapter
Public DS As System.Data.DataSet
Public CB As SqlCommandBuilder

Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Call GETNWDS()
        Call testDS()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub GETNWDS()
    '' opencustumorDataAdapterdaaset DS

    Dim connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("NW testConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim queryString As String = "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName FROM Customers where CustomerID='ALFKI'"

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    DA = New SqlDataAdapter(queryString, conn)
    DS = New System.Data.DataSet
    DA.Fill(DS)

    CustomerIDbox.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("CustomerID").ToString
    CompanyNamebox.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("CompanyName").ToString
    ContactNamebox.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("ContactName").ToString

End Sub

Public Sub testDS()
    Try
        Dim v As String
        v = "in DS= " + DS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("ContactName").ToString
        Textbox.Text = v

        'Error after clicking the save button:
        '   System.NullReferenceException
        '   Object reference Not set to an instance of an object.  
        '   at NW_DB_update_test.NWtest.testDS() in S: \P2 S VS tests\NW DB update test\NW DB update test\NWtest.aspx.vb:line 46


    Catch x As Exception
        Textbox.Text = x.ToString
    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

========================================================================================

Comment: This is because DS does not have any data in it at that moment. In a web context every request (page load, button click etc) to the server results in a fresh execution of the C# script. The values of variables do not persist between requests, you can't just pick up where you left off like you can with a desktop app. Read about the page lifecycle of an ASP.NET page (it's even more peculiar than other web technologies) before you go too much further. MS has articles about it.

Comment: "In a web context every request (page load, button click etc) to the server results in a fresh execution of the C# script." do this mean that in C# the DS is refilled automatically?  Is this the dame in VB?

Comment: VB/C# is no difference. No i mean the opposite, it is _not_ refilled automatically, that's why your variable is empty. BTW what code runs at the postback? None of the above code would run at a postback (i.e. when your button is clicked) as far as I can see, unless you have bound one of these Subs to the button via your aspx code? Have you actually shown the code on which the error occurs? Can you show us the button? What event handler does it bind to?

Comment: The problem is solved.
Thanks to your comment about refreshing DS, I discovered why DS was not updated,
The cause was that the line
“If Not IsPostBack Then”
Was  the wrong place.
That was very stupid of me I did not know about the refresh .
Now updating the DB works OK.
Thank you veryvery  much for the effort and the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but as ADyson explained, the variables you have declared on page load are non-existent after the postback. On the other hand, if you just want to read the `ContactName`, you can get it directly from the textbox it was written to, as controls do persist between postbacks, if not otherwise stated.

```
Textbox.Text=ContactNamebox.Text
```